# Kryo Class Registration

Tags: java, kryo

Though I have registered this

```
private static inner class EntryWithID
```

[kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#registration) throws

> *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException* (Class is not registered: shared.SharedObjectFactory$Segment$EntryWithID
>   ).

```
kryo.register(Class.forName("shared.SharedObjectFactory$Segment$EntryWithID")); 

kryo.register(Array.newInstance(Class.forName("shared.SharedObjectFactory$Segment$EntryWithID"), 0).getClass());
```

I guess, the problem is for deeply nested inner class `EntryWithID`. Am I doing anything wrong in the registration?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the trace log of Kryo and check.

Since Kryo use Minlog library for logging, you can enable the trace level log by adding `com.esotericsoftware.minlog.Log.TRACE();` to the source code.

Enabling TRACE level log will print the details about all the classes which are registered with Kryo.